# MySQL paritioning by YEAR: date vs timestamp

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I've got a huge table that I'm about to partition. It has a compound 4-element primary key. One of its element is record time, which is a good candidate to be the paritioning key. MySQL manual gives lots of examples where `DATE` field with `RANGE YEAR` is a very efficient partitioning key.

My problem is that I have `timestamp` instead of `date`. [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-range.html) state that it is possible to use `timestamp`:

> Beginning with MySQL 5.1.43, it is also possible to partition a table
>   by RANGE based on the value of a TIMESTAMP column, using the
>   UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function

but it doesn't say anything about performance. The question is: which of `date`, `timestamp` is going to be faster as a partitioning key? If `DATE` is better, I'm considering changing the primary key. I'm gonna divide all data across one-year partitions or half-year partitions.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to know for sure it to see a benchmark.

I never did one so my answer could be wrong.

In my opinion, the `DATE` should be faster than the `TIMESTAMP` since it stores less information so it would be easier to work with. Also since it was the first to be supported for partitioning should tell you that it could be better implemented (not saying that the `TIMESTAMP` version would be badly implemented).

But my question to you would be if `DATE` would be a good replacement for `TIMESTAMP` since you will lose a lot of precision.

Answer (score 0):

Another important check is the amount of bytes per field.

DATE = 3 bytes

TIMESTAMP = 4 bytes

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-requirements.html